# Is there any official word yet on when Ant-Man 2 is coming to theaters?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

I'm very excited about the prospect of an Ant-Man sequel and I've heard dates ranging from 2018 to 2020 but haven't actually seen proof-positive that Part II has actually been confirmed for sure.

**Is there an actual release date that Marvel has *officially* set yet?**

Comment: All the movies are listed on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#Feature_films

Comment: Now that we have an official release date, perhaps you might consider an acceptance?

Answer (score 13):

### Update 2

The film achieved a US release on the 6th July, 2018 but the UK release was pushed back to the 3rd August, 2018 to avoid a conflict with the World Cup.

### Update

The film now has an [official release date](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5095030/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt), premiering in the UK on the 29th June, 2018 and in the US on the 6th July, 2018

---

According to Marvel.com, a sequel to Ant-Man (titled 'Ant-Man and the Wasp') is in pre-production, scheduled for release in July 2018 with [Paul Rudd](https://web.archive.org/web/20170607180302/http://www.denofgeek.com:80/uk/movies/ant-man-2/47751/ant-man-and-the-wasp-to-begin-filming-in-july), [Evangline Lilly](https://twitter.com/EvangelineLilly/status/866834776837152768?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=http://heroichollywood.com/evangeline-lilly-fitting-wasp-suit/) and [Michael Pena](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/movies/movie-news/michael-pena-star-sony-horror-920657/) reprising their roles.

> Following our hero’s debut adventure in this summer’s “Ant-Man,” Scott
> Lang will return alongside Hope Van Dyne on July 6, 2018 with Marvel’s
> “Ant-Man and the Wasp.” The sequel will mark the first Marvel Studios
> film named after its heroine.
>
> <sub><sup>[MARVEL STUDIOS PHASE 3 UPDATE - MARVEL.COM](https://web.archive.org/web/20211010164048/https://www.webcitation.org/6c83EJZBL?url=http://marvel.com/news/movies/25244/marvel_studios_phase_3_update?linkId=17794776#axzz4iQ2iVVtu)</sup></sub>

Principal photography is due to start within the next 1-2 months.

> *“Assuming everything stays on schedule, we start filming Ant-Man and
> the Wasp in June [2017].”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ant-Man and the Wasp: Kevin Feige Confirms June Filming Start Date](https://screenrant.com/ant-man-2-wasp-filming-start-kevin-feige/)</sup></sub>

Comment: I really do appreciate this info thank you very much! Yeah I was just trying to make it sound too professional I guess, the question lol sorrry bout that. Thus I made it a bit too wordy! This is exciting to know the date I LOVED Ant Man!

Comment: “the UK release was pushed back to the 3rd August, 2018 to avoid a conflict with the World Cup” — there was literally no way they could have predicted that the World Cup would be on.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I'm sure it came as a terrible shock to them to suddenly realise that they'd done something monumentally dumb that would cost them millions of pounds.

Comment: @Valorum: if there’s no extended soccer sequence in Ant-Man 2 then I, for one, will be extremely disappointed.

Answer (score -3):

Marvel announced it's release date at the starting of phase 4

It's 6 July 2018
[image: CHECK IT OUT]

Comment: What is the source for this? What you show is just the Google blurb, and Google is not the most trusted authority on this. Valorum's answer already provides information from authorities - can you provide anything that is _credibly_ more accurate than it?